# rules engine combining node.js in server and php in ui

Tags: database, node.js, drools, rule-engine

I am starting an application that combines many components:

- node.js in server side for its light asynchronous event-driven behaviour ( and also for the features socket.io ) ==> it will capture data recieved on socket port, store in database, refresh UI and trigger events.
- a php framework for the ui part, fulfilling the usal treatement and rendering html pages.
- and of course a database server, most likely to collect shared data

Other components can be added as the overall architecture evolve, but for now, my main concern is to integrate a rules engine somewhere overthere. 
 So the required process is:

- a connected user will define his own rules via web interface.
- those rules will be stored in database in a specefic format ( to be figured out )
- these same rules are processed at runtime via a rules engine ( probably compatible with node.js )
- when constraints are met, the matching events should be excuted

I do have a previous experience with rules engines, normally when it comes to distributed systems, I would go for a one supporting API or soap communication to link different environments ( I have done that between .net and JAVA apps using openrules ). 
But, in this case, I am considering [drools](http://drools.jboss.org/) as it has a node.js compatible version [nools](https://github.com/C2FO/nools). So my idea, is that user rules will be stored in DB via drools which should have the same syntaxe to be exectude via nools server side.

At this point, I am still gathering details to pick the adequate architecture. Has anyone gone through this before. I would really appreciate your feedback regarding your experiences with rules engines in such use-cases.

Thanks

Comment: Nools may be a Rete implementation, but it's a long way from being anything like Drools. Taking a quick look at those nools docs you linked, there are some similarities in rule structure, but the syntax is not the same as the Drools DRL syntax. So Rules created using Drools/Workbench will not be loadable in nools.

Comment: I see, so do you have any recommandations on what fits with such requirements ?

Comment: I guess either use a JVM-based back-end to integrate with Drools properly. It doesn't take much effort to expose it as a web service. Otherwise, plan how to manage your nools rules yourself. Note that the latest version of Drools stores rules in Git rather than in a DB.